# Spring security multiple authention-providers depending on from address

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have set up Spring Security with multiple Authenticators before,  but I have a new requirement to use one authenticator for one URL and one for another URL.

So if a user goes to xxx.myapp.com  -- they will get a simple username/pass that submits to /j_spring_security_check

BUT if they come to yyy.myapp.com  -- they will get redirected to a SAML IDP, and then back to me.

Ignoring for now syncing up the user details service...(ug) What is the best way to achieve this?

I think the only way to do this is with some sort of filter, but I hate adding a filter for every call, even after they are authenticated.

Thoughts?